# Overridable argument type

Tags: typescript, generics

I have generic class `C<T>` containing method `f` expecting argument of type `T`.

```
let c = new C<string>();

c.f('a');  // should work
c.f(1);    // shouldn't work
```

I would like to add ability to override this argument type:

```
c.f<number>(1)  // should work
```

The problem is I cannot figure out how this function signature should look like.

I tried those two solutions:

```
class C<T> {
  f<O = T>(arg: O) {} 
}

class C<T> {
  f<O>(arg: O extends undefined ? T : O) {} 
}
```

but in both cases ts allow `c.f(1)` which I don't want to.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCA8AVAfNA3gKGtAZvA8sgBRgBOA5gFzT7QCmAHgC50B2AJjAK4d04CWrOu2gB+aImjV8ASnQBfaBnkYMIOk2jBoAXmhCA7nHgQmpQeWIyA3KuAA6HEQDkYZzeyfsAem-QIABYA9lwgIgZBpADWGA5OAIweXl6+-sGh7KzOmhHRsY7wrFwAtgBGdKTEiT5+gSFh0LkxQA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript will infer type parameters based on arguments. There is a proposal to make non inferential parameters, but this hasn't moved anywhere for a while, we can however use the workaround suggested in the [GH issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-504042546) on the topic. This `NoInfer` type will confuse the compiler enough to give up on inferring from a specific parameter.

If typescript can't infer a type parameter it will fallback the default type, the constraint, or `unknown`. We can use the default type to specify a value that will probably not be valid for the parameter (we could also use `never`, but a string message is usually more helpful)

```
type NoInfer<T> = [T][T extends any ? 0 : never];
class C<T> {
  f(arg: T): void
  f<O = "No explict type parameter was provided">(arg: NoInfer<O>) : void
  f(arg: unknown) {} 
}

let c = new C<string>();

c.f('a');       // works
c.f(1);         // does not work
c.f<number>(1)  // works
```

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gSQHYDMICcA8AVAfFAXigG1sBdUqCAD2AiQBMBnKAQyRCgH4oAGKAFxQkEAG4YyAbgBQAYwA2rJiwDCOfAG9pUKCgAUrdAHMh2AJRDRcAJYNtuzAHlCUAETwq1MPOuzgUUEgoMENWAFsIOnQoAHclYPQ4UVsIBldcA2MheGQ0LEdcM0EoK1t7fUMTKABXJABrJDgYpCKNAF8oaTbpaXlIqFkXERioNSZgdGskIwyzGTkAOn0AclZluZ1NnQB6bdi4dDqmRf0ARg2trd2oBjgIFkb-GIO6k8wkarCAIwwM8529s9DscgA)

Answer (score 0):

You could use it like this

```
(c as any as C<number>).f(1)  // works
```